# How to short a array on date using php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, date

> **I want to sort the php array by `t_date`?**

```
 Array (
        [0] => Array ( 
                    [in_out] => I 
                    [sale_pur] => P 
                    [sale_pur_type] => Purchase 
                    [party_name] => SRIDHAR DISTRIBUTION AGENCY 
                    [ent_no] => 3251 
                    [t_date] => 2018-06-20 
                    [inv_no] => SD-4439 
                    [v_type] => Purchase 
                    [t_qty] => 10 
                    [item_rate] => 81.89 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [in_out] => I 
                        [sale_pur] => P 
                        [sale_pur_type] => Purchase 
                        [party_name] => SRIDHAR DISTRIBUTION AGENCY 
                        [ent_no] => 3332 
                        [t_date] => 2018-06-27 
                        [inv_no] => SD-4939 
                        [v_type] => Purchase 
                        [t_qty] => 10 
                        [item_rate] => 81.89 ) 
        [2] => Array ( [in_out] => I 
                        [sale_pur] => P 
                        [sale_pur_type] => Purchase 
                        [party_name] => SRIDHAR DISTRIBUTION AGENCY 
                        [ent_no] => 3592 
                        [t_date] => 2018-07-25 
                        [inv_no] => SD-6906 
                        [v_type] => Purchase 
                        [t_qty] => 10 
                        [item_rate] => 81.89 ) 
        [3] => Array ( [in_out] => O 
                        [sale_pur] => S 
                        [sale_pur_type] => Sales 
                        [party_name] => LIFE LINE MEDICAL CENTER 
                        [ent_no] => 5879 
                        [t_date] => 2018-04-01 
                        [inv_no] => 11 
                        [v_type] => Sales 
                        [t_qty] => 6 
                        [item_rate] => 82.03 
                        ) 
        [4] => Array ( [in_out] => O 
                        [sale_pur] => S 
                        [sale_pur_type] => Sales 
                        [party_name] => BEENA MEDICALS 
                        [ent_no] => 5877 
                        [t_date] => 2018-04-01 
                        [inv_no] => 9 
                        [v_type] => Sales 
                        [t_qty] => 1 
                        [item_rate] => 82.03 ) 
        [5] => Array ( [in_out] => O 
                        [sale_pur] => S 
                        [sale_pur_type] => Sales 
                        [party_name] => BEENA MEDICALS 
                        [ent_no] => 6053 
                        [t_date] => 2018-04-11 
                        [inv_no] => 185 
                        [v_type] => Sales 
                        [t_qty] => 1 
                        [item_rate] => 82.03 )
        [25] => Array ( [in_out] => O 
                        [sale_pur] => DC 
                        [sale_pur_type] => Debit Note 
                        [party_name] => AKDM 
                        [ent_no] => 27 
                        [t_date] => 2018-08-05 
                        [inv_no] => DN/27 
                        [v_type] => Sales 
                        [t_qty] => 1.000000 
                        [item_rate] => 82.03 ) 
        [26] => Array ( [in_out] => I 
                        [sale_pur] => DC 
                        [sale_pur_type] => Credit Note 
                        [party_name] => soumen das 
                        [ent_no] => 29 
                        [t_date] => 2018-08-05 
                        [inv_no] => CN/9 
                        [v_type] => Sales 
                        [t_qty] => 0.500000 
                        [item_rate] => 82.03 ) 
                        );
```

Comment: Can you  intent your question

Answer (score 0):

You can use usort

```
<?php
$items = [['t_date' => '2018-06-20'], ['t_date' => '2018-06-27'], ['t_date' => '2018-07-25 ']];

usort($items, function($a, $b) {
     return $a['t_date'] > $b['t_date'];
});

var_dump($items);
```